# php -Merging an Array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, merge

I have two array which i want to merge in a specific way in php.
So i need your help in helping me with it as i tried and failed.

So say i have two arrays:

```
$array1= array(
    "foo"        => 3,
    "bar"        => 2,
    "random1"    => 4,
);

$array2= array(
    "random2"    => 3,
    "random3"    => 4,
    "foo"        => 6,
);
```

Now when during merging i would like the **common key's values to be added**.
So like **foo** exists in **array1**  and in **array2** so when merging array1 with array 2 i should get `"foo" => "9"`

I better illustration would be the final array which looks like this:

```
$array1= array(
    "foo"        => 9,
    "bar"        => 2,
    "random1"    => 4,
    "random2"    => 3,
    "random3"    => 4,
);
```

So again i would like the values of the common keys to be added together and non common keys to be added to array or a new array

I hope i was clear enough

Thanks,
Vidhu

Comment: `foreach` through `$array2`, add the value if an existing key in `$array1`, append item if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that:

```
function mergeValues() {
    $result = array();
    $arraysToMerge = func_get_args();
    foreach ($arraysToMerge as $array) {
       foreach($array as $key => $value) {
           $result[$key] += $value;
       }
    }

    return $result;
}

$res = mergeValues($array1, $array2, $array3); // Can pass any ammount of arrays to a function.
```

Comment: Compliments, it is really an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach($array1 as $k => $v)
 {
     If (isset($array2[$k]))
         $array1[$k] += $array2[$k];
 }
 foreach($array2 as $k => $v)
 {
     If (!isset($array1[$k]))
         $array1[$k] = $array2[$k];
 }
```